# Custom IP in CURL

Tags: php, curl

This doesnt work. Please help!

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
```

Answer (score 6):

The `REMOTE_ADDR` is not user-provided, it's taken from the TCP connection. There's no such thing as a "custom IP".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, because the IP address comes from the TCP/IP data packet. The only way to change IP address is using a proxy server

Answer (score 1):

You can't send `REMOTE_ADDR` as there is no such HTTP header. Even if you could, the response would be received by the specified host (`REMOTE_ADDR`) and not you. What you are trying to do is called IP Spoofing. You can read more [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ip-spoofing-introduction).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually have that IP, don't bother trying as others have said. If however you have that IP on your server, and just want to choose which one of your ips to use on an external connections, you can use `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_INTERFACE,'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');` (the second argument can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name).